# SVN won't commit unversioned files even though they show up with svn status

Tags: svn, macos

I'm running into difficulty setting up a new project into source control. I've imported a project into subversion and on the surface everything seems to be running fine. However, whenever I add a new file into the project, even though it comes up as unversioned when I run svn status, it isn't checked in when i try and check in, either using svn ci -m 'msg' or when I try in my Versions OS X svn client.

here's some example output from svn status:

```
?      Assets/Placeholder Images/shopping_list_1.png
```

And when I try to check-in it only checks in those files already versioned. The rest are ignored silently!

Any ideas on how I might solve this?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses guys, really appreciated. I think what confused me is that my usual svn client, subclipse within eclipse, does the add on your behalf. Would be good to have this done automatically (or at least the option to) within XCode/Versions on OS X too.

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to add the file to your working copy:

`svn add Assets/Placeholder Images/shopping_list_1.png`

then you can check it in to the repository:

`svn ci -m "Added shopping list placeholder image"`

Comment: to be pedantic: "svn add" does not "add a file to repository". It only adds the file to the set of versioned files in your local working copy. This has no effect on the repository until you commit.

Answer (score 4):

The question mark in the first column of the status output means the file isn't ignore, but also isn't being versioned.  It's svn's way of saying "huh? what do you want me to do with this?"

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this plugin for OS X. It's like TortoiseSVN for Windows users.

http://scplugin.tigris.org/